# How to convert a list of enity object to page object in Spring MVC (JPA)?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, pagination, spring-data

I have a `List` of entities.
How do I convert it to `Page` Object using Spring MVC 4 and Spring Data JPA?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

There is a [`Page` implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageImpl.html) for that:

```
final Page<Something> page = new PageImpl<>(theListOfSomething);
```

Comment: it doesn't divide them into pages but returns all the items in one page

Comment: It Will have error

Answer (score 64):

There is one more [Constructor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageImpl.html#PageImpl-java.util.List-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-long-) :

```
Page<Something> page = new PageImpl<>(listOfsomething, pageable, listOfsomething.size());
```

Comment: Here is how to create the `pageable` object: `Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, size);` Note that `pageNumber` is *zero-based* and that `Pageable` and `PageRequest` are imported from `org.springframework.data.domain`.
For more info, see [Pageable documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html)

Comment: @Mehraj Malik mine is not working with this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62485592/pageable-in-spring-for-paging-on-listobject-is-not-working

Answer (score 8):

I think you will need to fetch the correct page content as well.

```
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(offset, limit);

List<Product> products = getProducts();

int total = products.size();
int start = toIntExact(pageRequest.getOffset());
int end = Math.min((start + pageRequest.getPageSize()), total);

List<Product> output = new ArrayList<>();

if (start <= end) {
    output = products.subList(start, end);
}

return new PageImpl<>(
    output,
    pageRequest,
    total
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally, controller should receive a `Pageable` object as parameter. The `Pageable` object contains page number, page size and sorting information.

Then you can query all entities from `JpaRepository` with sorting and generate `Page` object:

```
List<Entity> allList = jpaRepository.findAll(pageable.getSort());

List<Entity> pageList = allList.stream()
    .skip(pageable.getOffset())
    .limit(pageable.getPageSize())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

return new PageImpl<>(pageList, pageable, allList.size());
```

Comment: You can use pageable.getOffset() for skipping, you don't need to multiply

Comment: Thanks @CptWasp, applied to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a list to the function to make it a pageable object. If the start value of the sublist is less than the list size, it returns the empty content.

```
  public Page<?> toPage(List<?> list, Pageable pageable) {
        int start = (int) pageable.getOffset();
        int end = Math.min((start + pageable.getPageSize()), list.size());
        if(start > list.size())
            return new PageImpl<>(new ArrayList<>(), pageable, list.size());
        return new PageImpl<>(list.subList(start, end), pageable, list.size());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers all assume the list is what you wish to return. Here is what you can do to perform pagination on a list containing **total** records.

```
//pageNum starts with 1
//size: page size
//totalRecords, total records
Page<Record> myMethod(int pageNum, int size, List<MyRecord> totalRecords){
    if(pageNum<1){
        pageNum = 1;
    }
    if(size < 1){
        size = 10;
    }
    //spring page starts with 0
    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(pageNum-1, size);
    //when pageNum * size is too big(bigger than list.size()), totalRecords.subList() will throw a exception, we need to fix this
    if(pageable.getOffset() > list.size()){
            pageable = new PageRequest(0, size);
    }
    List<MyRecord> pageRecords = totalRecords.subList(pageable.getOffset(), Math.min(pageable.getOffset() + pageable.getPageSize(), totalRecords.size()));
    
    Page springPage = new PageImpl<>(pageRecords, pageable, totalRecords.size());
    return springPage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T> PageData buildCustomPagedData(List<T> data, Pageable pageable) {
    List<T> model = new ArrayList<>();
    int start = VALUE_ZERO;
    if (!Objects.equals(pageable.getPageNumber(), FIRST_INDEX)) {
        start = (pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize());
    }
    for (int i = start; i < start + pageable.getPageSize(); i++) {
        if (i < data.size()) {
            model.add(data.get(i));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return PageData.builder()
            .model(model)
            .totalElements(data.size())
            .currentPage(pageable.getPageNumber() + INT_ONE)
            .totalPages((data.size() / pageable.getPageSize()) + INT_ONE)
            .build();
}
```