# Filtering a Page

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
Page<K2Agents> iterable = k2AgentsRepository.findAllByTeamIdIn(teamIds, pageRequest);
List<K2Agents> iterable1 = iterable.stream()
                                   .filter(i->i.getLastName().equals(searchName))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
return iterable1;
```

I want to filter `iterable` by a string `searchName`. The final result should be a `Page`. In this code `iterable1` return nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "final result should be a `Page`"? Also "In this code iterable1 return nothing" is confusing since `.collect(Collectors.toList())` ensures that result will be `List<K2Agents>`, possibly empty but still a list so it is not nothing (I know it is nitpicking but to get correct answers it is good to be as precise as we can).

Comment: I mean iterable1 should return a Page. I printed iterable and it returns a Page, but iterables1 returns nothing. thx

Comment: Try this `iterable.map(k2Agent -> k2Agent.getLastName().equals(searchName) ? k2Agent : null);`

Comment: You should not do what you write in the text because it breaks the semantic Page contract which promises that the Page has either a given size or there is no next Page. 
Either do the filtering on the database (which would be smart anyways) or you return a List (which your code already does).  In the later case you should use page.filter().get().collect().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a List of enity Object to Page Object in Spring Mvc Jpa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136679/how-to-convert-a-list-of-enity-object-to-page-object-in-spring-mvc-jpa)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First filter the `Page<K2Agent>` by using `stream` and finally create `Page` object using `PageImpl`

```
List<K2Agents> result = iterable.getContent()
                                   .stream()
                                   .filter(i->i.getLastName().equals(searchName))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());

Page<K2Agent> r = new PageImpl<K2Agent>(result);
```

Comment: `Page.map` operation take a `Function<K2Agents,K2Agents>` here!

Comment: Thx, but I got this: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList$Itr cannot be cast to org.springframework.data.domain.Page   @Deadpool